# how to pass a variable to an XPathExpression

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

i want to pass the value of a variable in XPathExpression. I want to put the id value in a variable. How can I do that? Below is the code;

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//Number[@id=1]/Movies/text()");
```

Above, I want to put the value of id in a variable. I tried int num =1 but doesn't works.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String yourArg= "1";
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//Number[@id="+yourArg+"]/Movies/text()");
```

Comment: Anyway to change it after the compile?